# how to create a bash fuction to replace line or append to file

Tags: bash, function, awk, sed, grep

Is there a more simple way to do the following below? Maybe a single command that will replace the text if it exists, if not append text to the file.  I need to do this for various files and want to find a way to put in in a function.  the line formatting will vary slightly between, I put 2 example below.

```
#If grep exists then sed line, else echo to end of file
grep -q '^sometext' /file1.txt && sed -i "" "s/^sometext.*/sometext $newvar/" /file1.txt || echo "sometext $newvar" >> /file1.txt
grep -q '^someothertext' /file2.txt && sed -i "" "s/^someothertext.*/someothertext=$othernewvar/" /file1.txt || echo "someothertext=$othernewvar" >> /file1.txt
```

Comment: Would it ever be possible to make *more* than one replacement? I think it should be possible in `sed` to write a script that contains both the replacement code *and* the append code, but the append code is only reached if no replacement occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself using grep+sed or multiple seds or various other combinations of tools just to manipulate text, it's time to consider simply using awk instead:

```
awk -v key="sometext" -v sep=" " -v new="$newvar" '
sub("^"key".*",key sep new) { f=1 }
{ print }
END { if (!f) print key sep new }
' file

awk -v key="someothertext" -v sep="=" -v new="$othernewvar" '
sub("^"key".*",key sep new) { f=1 }
{ print }
END { if (!f) print key sep new }
' file
```

Note that the above use regexps and backreference-enabled replacement strings just like sed does so you'd have to worry about escaping metacharacters (`.`, `*`, `?`, `+`, `&`, etc. - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/1745001) in the key and new text. Since you're using awk, though, you can use literal strings instead:

```
awk -v key="sometext" -v sep=" " -v new="$newvar" '
index(key)==1 { $0 = key sep new; f=1 }
{ print }
END { if (!f) print key sep new }
' file
```

and then you don't have to worry about that. The only character you DO still have to think about with the above is backslash because `\t` will be translated to a tab character, etc. when doing a variable assignment with `-v` but there's a simple tweak for that if it's an issue.

Comment: had to remove `key` from the output but other than that this is what i needed, thanks!